# Finitely generated modules in exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

For $A$-modules and homomorphisms $0\to M'\stackrel{u}{\to}M\stackrel{v}{\to}M''\to 0$ is exact. Prove if $M'$ and $M''$ are fintely generated then $M$ is finitely generated.

Comment: Do this for vector spaces. Then do exactly the same for modules.

Comment: See the proof of the lemma of my answer to this question.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231058/noetherian-rings-and-modules

Comment: You do not need $u$ to be injective, by the way. The result is true without that assumption.

Answer (score 21):

Suppose $M'$ is generated by $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $M''$ is generated by $z_1,\dots,z_m$.
Let $v(y_i) = z_i$ for $i = 1,\dots,m$.
Let $x \in M$.
Then there exist $b_1,\dots,b_m \in A$ such that $v(x) = b_1z_1 + \cdots + b_mz_m$.
Then $v(x) = v(b_1y_1 + \cdots + b_my_m)$.
Hence $x - (b_1y_1 + \cdots + b_my_m) \in \operatorname{Ker}v$.
Since $\operatorname{Ker}v = \operatorname{Im}u$, there exist $a_1,\dots,a_n \in A$ such that $x - (b_1y_1 + \cdots + b_my_m) = a_1u(x_1) + \cdots + a_nu(x_n)$.
Hence $M$ is generated by $u(x_1),\dots,u(x_n), y_1,\dots,y_m$.

Answer (score 5):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\coker{\operatorname{Coker}}$

Since $M',M''$ are finitely generated, we can pick surjections $s_{M'}:R^m\to M'$ and $s_{M''}:R^n\to M''$. Now consider the following commutative diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0 @>>>R^m @>>> R^m\oplus R^n @>>> R^n@>>>0 \\
@. @VV{s_{M'}}V @. @VV{s_{M''}}V\\
0 @>>>M' @>{u}>>M @>{v}>> M'' @>>> 0\\
\end{CD}

where the vertical arrows are the surjections. Then as $M\to M''$ is a surjection and $R^n$ is projective (since free), we get map $w:R^n\to M$ so that the composition $v\circ w$ is the same as the surjection $s_{M''}:R^n\to M''$. We can then define a map from $s_M:R^{m+n}=R^m\oplus R^n\to M$ as follows: send $(x,y)\mapsto (u\circ s_{M'})(x) + w(y)$.

Now by snake lemma, we have exact sequence $\coker{s_{M'}}\to\coker{s_M}\to\coker{s_{M''}}$. Then $\coker{s_{M'}}, \coker{s_{M''}}$ are trivial by assumption, so is $\coker{s_{M}}$.
$\endgroup$

Answer (score 2):

I would consider this as a very special case of the [Horseshoe lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_lemma) and prove it like that. This is essentially the same prove as in Makoto Kato wrote down, but his is written down more elementary.

Comment: This can be a good comment, but is definitely not an answer!