# If $L\rightarrow M\rightarrow N$ is a short exact sequence and L and N are finite over A, then so is M

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $L\rightarrow M\rightarrow N$ is a short exact sequence of A-modules and $L$ and $N$ are finite over A, then so is M.

Comment: are you trying to prove this? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: here I don't know how to make $M$ into a quotient of a f.g. A-module.

Comment: Calc1DropOut: yes.

Comment: And what about his second question?

Comment: This is an abstract duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/234753/264) (in the question above, just replace $L$ and $N$ with the appropriate pieces making this a short exact sequence).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take generating sets for $L$ and $N$.  Push the generating set of $L$ into $M$ and for each element of the generating set in $N$ choose a preimage in $M$.  These two sets together are a finite set in $M$ and you should be able to show that it generates.