# $M + N$ and $M \cap N$ are finitely generated $A$-modules implies $M$ and $N$ finitely generated using exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $0 \to M_1 \to M \to M_2 \to 0$ be an exact sequence of $A$-modules.

i) Prove: If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are finitely generated, then $M$ is too.

ii) Let $M$ and $N$ be sub-modules of an $A$-module $L$. Assume that
$M+N$ and $M\cap N$  are finitely generated $A$-modules.
Prove that $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated $A$-modules.

If have proved the first part, but i don't see how to do the second part. I tried to use the first part, so to find an exact sequence with $M$ in the middle and finitely generated modules in place of $M_1$ and $M_2$, but I can't find a surjective map $M \to P$ (for some f.g. $A$-module) in the sequence:

$$0 \to M\cap N \to M \to P \to 0$$

any hints/help would be appreciated.

Comment: see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234753/finitely-generated-modules-in-exact-sequence

Answer (score 1):

Simply take
$$P= M/(M \cap N)$$
and recall that this is finitely generated since there is a canonical isomorphism
$$M/(M \cap N) \cong (M+N)/N$$

Answer (score 0):

For i) note that the sum of $A^n \twoheadrightarrow M_1 \to M$ and a lift of $A^m \twoheadrightarrow M_2$ to $M$, surjects onto $M$.

For ii) note that you get short exact sequences $0 \to M\cap N \to M \to (M+N)/N\to 0$.